# after Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 => 17.04 upgrade - recurring glitch with autosuspend(?) on 1 min intervals

Tags: graphics, suspend, 17.04, ubuntu-gnome

I recently upgraded Ubuntu Gnome from 16.10 to 17.04 and have installed all subsequent updates.

I am experiencing a sort of glitch where every minute (on the nose) my desktop freezes up momentarily (a couple of seconds), any open windows get a maybe 20 pixels smaller on each side and a square border fills that space. Then the screen flashes (transitions) to the login screen background (just the background, no login form or top panel widgets) and then back immediately.

I can't figure out what is happening or find a similar experience from someone else online. My guess is maybe an auto-suspend enable/disable issue. The first time it occurred I was in full screen and the autosuspend enable/disable dialog boxes would appear each time. But it occurs after boot without openning any applications too now.

Does anyone have any suggestions for solving this issue?

This is a Gigabyte Brix
Details lists:

- CPU: Intel® Core™ i3-4010U CPU @ 1.70GHz × 4
- Graphics: Intel® Haswell
  Mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was due to an errant Gnome extension or combination of extensions; I turned them off and the problem was eliminated. I have yet to go through them one by one to trigger the issue.

Comment: traced back to Bing wallpaper changer. Found there was an update available - did that. still causing glitch.